# System.Net.Mail.MailMessage, Adding an image to a mail message

Tags: c#, .net

I need to add images to a mail message and need them to be place at a specific point. Nothing too fancy just after some text but before some more text. 
Is this possible??
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use HTML email and link the image to a external resource. There are [ways](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/inkrajesh.aspx) to actually embed, but their compatibility is varied at best.

Comment: +1. Embedding always caused us problems with some clients, so we go this route every time.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to create a html message with MIME headers. Then you could either use an image from some webserver (which many Email-clients won't display without user intervention) or add the image as attachement to the mail-